# Create IActorRef from path string in Akka.net

Tags: akka.net

How to create an IActorRef from the path as string? Is there a way like:

```
string path = "akka://Somesystem/user/myactor";

IActorRef actorRef = ActorRef.FromPath(path); // this is pseudo-code

actorRef.Tell(...);
```

I don't wont to bloat my message classes/structs and also the API interfaces with the the explicit dependency to Akka.net IActorRef type (maybe switch to other implementation like Proto.Actor behind the curtain).

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. If you want to get an `IActorRef` you'll need a dependency to Akka.Net since that type is part of the framework. Now, since an `ActorSelection` can address multiple Actors at once (using wildcards) there is no good way to get the `IActorRef` from an `ActorSelection`. The correct way would be construct an `ActorSelection` and send a `Identify` command to it. In the Actor which would receive the command you would then reply with an `Identified` event. And in the original Actor you could then use the `Sender` property of type `IActorRef` upon arrival of the event.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not.  The only way to create an actor is to use the `ActorOf` method.  From the [docs](https://getakka.net/articles/concepts/addressing.html#summary-actorof-vs-actorselection):

> What the above sections described in some detail can be summarized and memorized easily as follows:
>
> - `ActorOf` only ever creates a new actor, and it creates it as a direct
>     child of the context on which this method is invoked (which may be
>     any actor or actor system).
> - `ActorSelection` only ever looks up existing actors when messages are delivered, i.e. does not create actors, or verify existence of
>     actors when the selection is created

The [signature](https://getakka.net/api/Akka.Actor.ActorSystem.html#Akka_Actor_ActorSystem_ActorOf_Akka_Actor_Props_System_String_) for `ActorOf` requires a Props property when creating actors, with an optional string for the actor name.  This can be called from either the actor system itself or from within an actor's context.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you describe you want to tell to another actor a message by path.
Therefore you can use *ActorSelection*.
There is a petabridge blog post describing some recommendations for *ActorSelection* see: https://petabridge.com/blog/when-should-I-use-actor-selection/

However, you wrote: *I don't wont to bloat my message classes/structs and also the API interfaces with the the explicit dependency to Akka.net IActorRef type (maybe switch to other implementation like Proto.Actor behind the curtain).*

I don't understand exactly want is your current usecase. But as far I understand you, you don't want to have dependencies in your domain logic to Akka.net.

1. If you want to send messages from outside of the actor System to an actor you could implement a service with a interface, where you just put your message, and use inside there *ActorSelection* (The only place with dependencies to Akka.net.
2. If you want to send messages inside your actors to other actors, and you are worried you cannot exchange the infrastructure (replace Akka.net) you should try to move your business logic outside of the actor classes into domain classes, which are neutral the framework. And using Akka.net for the communication between your actors.